# How to use elisp to let user pick a date from calendar?

Tags: date, calendar, elisp

Just learn to write an interactive function in elisp:

If called with prefix, open calendar and get the date which is picked by user.

I try to do something like this:

```
(calendar)
(org-get-date-from-calendar)
```

It return today straight away instead of let user to pick a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've seen, the problem is that after invoking `(calendar)` your code simply continues and doesn't wait around for any interactions in the calendar window. You need to prevent the [emacs command loop](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command-Loop.html#Command-Loop) from continuing until the user has selected a date.

Setting up your own keys is one way to do this. For example, if you look at the [`org-read-date-minibuffer-local-map` variable](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org.el#n16570) in the [org-mode source code](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/), you can see that org-mode essentially takes over keys in calendar mode to allow the user to navigate the calendar while org-mode waits for the result. Studying this keymap and the [`org-eval-in-calendar` function](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/org.el#n17084) might give you some ideas on how to achieve what you want.

Another way to wait for the result is via [recursive-edit](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Recursive-Editing.html). The code below enters the calendar and, by calling `(recursive-edit)`, waits for the user to exit the calendar via the `q` key, which normally invokes `calendar-exit`. The code temporarily applies advice to that function to have it set a local variable to the date selected in the calendar before calling `calendar-exit` (via the `funcall`) and then exiting the recursive edit:

```
(let* (date
       (adv '(lambda (fn &rest args)
               (setq date (calendar-cursor-to-date))
               (funcall fn args)
               (exit-recursive-edit))))
  (advice-add 'calendar-exit :around adv)
  (calendar)
  (message "Select the desired date, then type `q' to exit.")
  (recursive-edit)
  (advice-remove 'calendar-exit adv)
  date)
```

Using advice can be a brittle approach, though. It potentially changes function semantics in unexpected ways — and [see this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Named-Functions.html#Advising-Named-Functions) for other potential problems — plus there are probably other issues lurking with this approach with respect to abnormal exits. You're better off using keymap approaches like those used in org-mode.

Answer (score 4):

I tried

```
(org-read-date)
```

And that worked for me

Comment: This solution seems way easier.

Comment: According to https://sachachua.com/blog/2015/08/org-mode-date-arithmetic/, you can also do `(interactive (list (org-read-date)))`.